# smarty dropdown with javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, smarty

I'm trying to make a friends list where you can click the button at the top for a drop down menu.

```
    <script>
var dropAll = false;    

function changeAllFriendsDrop()
{
   if (dropAll == false)
       {
               dropAll = true;
        }
        else
            {
                dropAll = false;
            }
}
</script>
```

My function is simple enough but when i try call it onClick it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<li role="heading" data-role="list-divider" style="color:#F25A97">

                    <a >      
                        <button onclick="changeAllFriendsDrop()">All Friends </button>
                    </a>
                        </li>

       {$friend = array("Josh","Phil","Paul","Sean")} 

                {if !empty($friend)}
                    {foreach $friend as $person}
                      <script> if (dropAll == true){ </script>
                        <li data-theme="a" style="color:#F25A97">
                               <a href="">
                            {$person}
                               </a>
                               <a align="left" style="size: 10px">
                               Last Seen: {$lastLocation}
                               </a>
                        </li>
                        <script> } </script>
                    {/foreach}
                {/if}
```

It doesn't seem to call the function so the if statement cannot be checked, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the script included in the page?

Comment: yer its at the top just like above.

Comment: I think the `{` and `}` in the first code example is parsed as a smarty delimiter. Check out {literal}, {ldelim} and {rdelim} on smarty documentation.

Comment: I've tried it and it still isn't doing anything, i think it's the if statement and the dropAll variable, but not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Your callback function `dropAll` isn't actually causing anything to change on the page, it is just setting a variable. The line `if (dropAll == true)` will only be evaluated once, and even then will not do anything useful - a JavaScript `if` like that won't tell the browser to hide content, that's just not how it works. (In fact, since each `<script>` tag is evaluated separately, you are probably getting a JavaScript error because there's no `}` in the first `<script>` tag.)

What you need to do is write a JavaScript function which actually toggles the visibility of those parts of the page. I would strongly recommend using a JavaScript library such as [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) rather than doing this in "plain" JavaScript.

For instance, if you gave each of the elements you want to toggle `class="togglableFriendItem"`, you could use the jQuery [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function like this:

```
function toggleAllFriendsDrop()
{
    $('.togglableFriendItem').toggle();
}
```